# What is the logic to this if statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having difficulty understanding the logic of this statement:

`if (current_user.has_role? :admin, current_user.active_org)`

Comment: Code can be rewrited like this:
`if current_user.has_role?(:admin, current_user.active_org)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_role?` is looking at both parameters and returning a boolean. This is probably `CanCan`, right? If so it's saying "Is the current user an admin of the current user's active 'org'?"

Please post your `Ability` class if you want a more exact answer.

Comment: Yes it is CanCan, you answered perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically testing whether admin or current_user.active_org is valid, based on whether has_role is set or not...  same as:

```
if (current_user.has_role)
  if (admin)
    stuff...
  end
else
  if (current_user.active_org)
    same stuff...
  end
end
```

but just more compressed.